# Как сделать кнопку неактивной до выбора radiobutton из radiogroup?

Tags: java, android

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                //Какой код прописать?
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не ясен, но, вообще, отключение виджетов делается вызовом метод `setEnabled(boolean enable)`

Т.е. вам надо, видимо, по какому то условию писать так:

```
boolean condition = ...;
someClassThatExtendsView.setEnabled(condition);
```